# Neat way to plot this correlation using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset

```
                        airline avail_seat_km_per_week   Number    Year
  1:                 Aer Lingus              320906734       2 1985-99
  2:                  Aeroflot*             1197672318      76 1985-99
  3:      Aerolineas Argentinas              385803648       6 1985-99
  4:                Aeromexico*              596871813       3 1985-99
  5:                 Air Canada             1865253802       2 1985-99
 ---                                                                           
108:      United / Continental*             7139291291      14 2000-14
109: US Airways / America West*             2455687887      11 2000-14
110:           Vietnam Airlines              625084918       1 2000-14
111:            Virgin Atlantic             1005248585       0 2000-14
112:            Xiamen Airlines              430462962       2 2000-14
```

These are some instances of the dataset:

```
data.frame(airline=c("Aer Lingus", "Aeroflot*", "Aerolineas Argentinas", "Aeromexico*", "Air Canada", "Aer Lingus", "Aeroflot*", "Aerolineas Argentinas", "Aeromexico*", "Air Canada"), Number=c(2, 76, 6, 3, 2,0 ,6,1,5,2), Year=c("1985-99", "1985-99", "1985-99", "1985-99", "1985-99", "2000-14", "2000-14", "2000-14", "2000-14", "2000-14"))
```

which includes the number of crashes of airlines around the world in 2 different periods, 85-99 and 00-14, I want to plot a scatterplot that displays the number of crashes in period 85-99 against period 00-14, what is a neat way to do it using dplyr and ggplot2 packages, preferably using pipes?.

Please let me know if there are something I could do to further specify the problem. Appreciate your help!

Comment: you will be more likely to get replies if you post your dataframe in a way we can easily copy-paste to R, such as `data.frame(airline=c("Aer Lingus", ...), Number=c(...), etc.)` and also describing what you have already tried with code examples

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Solarion Hi, I have added as what you suggested, I don't know if it's good enough?

Comment: And I'm thinking of lag or group_by something but I don't really have an idea... @GregorThomas

Comment: What goes on the x-axis and what goes on the y-axis of the plot?

Comment: Could you please edit your sample data so it runs? All the airline names need quotes or they will cause an error. Same for your years. `1985-99` is `1886` because `-` means subtraction unless you use quotes.

Comment: the first and third column in your example frame need quotation marks around every item, otherweise R will try to read them as variables and calculations. you also miss a number in the Numbers columns, and the last closing bracket is missing

Comment: Hi, thank you, I have edited it. I want one axis to be the number of crashes in 1985-99 for all airlines, and the other is the number of crashes in 2000-14 for those airlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asking for help with plots in general, and `ggplot`, it's helpful if you're very clear about what data goes with each dimension - x, y, color, etc.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# (calling your data d)
d %>%
  # widen the data so each plot dimension gets a column
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = Number) %>%
  # use backticks for non-standard column names (because of the dash in this case)
  ggplot(aes(x = `1985-99`, y = `2000-14`, color = airline)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]